# Iotivity scons build error

Tags: android, python, scons, iotivity

This is my build environment

- OS:OS X El Capitan 10.11.5
- Android SDK build-tool : 24.0.1
- Android NDK : 12
- Scons version : 2.5.0

This is build command

- SCons TARGET_OS=android TARGET_ARCH=armeabi-v7a TARGET_TRANSPORT=ALL RELEASE=1 SECURED=0 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/KangSengGil/Library/Android/sdk ANDROID_NDK=/Users/KangSengGil/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle ANDROID_GRADLE=/Library/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle
  scons: Reading SConscript files ...

To obtain .aar file, I have to build Iotivity project.
but Scons build is showing me some error.
I don`t know How i solve this problem. Please Answer This problem!! 
Thank you

Below shows the error

```
NameError: name 'SCons' is not defined:
File "/Users/KangSengGil/Documents/iotivity-1.1.0/SConstruct", line 28:
SConscript('build_common/SConscript')
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 604:
return method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 541:
return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 250:
exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
File "/Users/KangSengGil/Documents/iotivity-1.1.0/build_common/SConscript", line 386:
env.SConscript(target_os + '/SConscript')
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 541:
return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 250:
exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
File "/Users/KangSengGil/Documents/iotivity-1.1.0/build_common/android/SConscript", line 241:
SConscript(env.get('SRC_DIR') + '/extlibs/boost/SConscript')
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 604:
return method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 541:
return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.5.0/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 250:
exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
File "/Users/KangSengGil/Documents/iotivity-1.1.0/extlibs/boost/SConscript", line 35:
raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(msg)
```

Comment: I use Iotivity 1.1.0 version

Comment: How did you install SCons?

Comment: yes i did install scons !

Comment: I didn't ask if you did. I asked how you did. What command line did you use to install it on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo - please confirm.
SCons command is not found.
Maybe use 'scons' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

edit <iotivity_root>/extlibs/boost/SConscript

befor

```
if host_os == 'linux2' :
    boost_bootstrap = boost_base_name+os.sep+'bootstrap.sh'
else :
    msg="Host platform (%s) is currently not supported for boost builds" % host_os
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(msg)
```

after

```
if host_os == 'linux2' :
    boost_bootstrap = boost_base_name+os.sep+'bootstrap.sh'
else :
    if host_os == 'darwin' :
        boost_bootstrap = ''
    else :
        msg="Host platform (%s) is currently not supported for boost builds" % host_os
        raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(msg)
```

Comment: Hi @Gecko , I tried something like this but still found same error like above , really appreaciate for any kind suggestion :   if host_os.startswith("linux"):
        boost_bootstrap = boost_base_name + os.sep + 'bootstrap.sh'
    else:
        if host_os.startswith("darwin"):
           boost_bootstrap = ''
        else :
           msg = "Host platform (%s) is currently not supported for boost builds" % host_os
           raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(msg)